# German Comic - Pope Fighting Evil - Papst bekämpft das Böse

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to find out details of a comic I saw in a shop in Berlin, probably published sometime between the years 2000 - 2005.

The Pope is fighting evil, I seem to recall he's fighting a purple (or green?) woman. What was very distinctive is that the Pope has blond hair, blue eyes, a fit and muscled physique, and he's carrying machine guns and probably other weapons too. This Pope is *really* fighting evil!

I've searched online but my memory is too vague to get any luck. The comic that I'm trying to find is not [*Manos – Der Dämonenjäger*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manos_%E2%80%93_Der_D%C3%A4monenj%C3%A4ger_(Comic)) (*Manos - The Demon Hunter*).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***666* by Froideval & Tacito**

This series has demons invading the world and an action pope dealing damage to them. You can see him on the cover of the album and interior picture below. There is a recurring female character with purple hair, which probably is what you remember - see cover.

[image]

[image]

There is a short [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/666_(bande_dessin%C3%A9e)) in French about the series.

Comment: On 13 January 2021 someone made a comment to my question but the comment has disappeared. The comment said that the comic might have been "Battle Pope". I've bought a copy of Battle Pope but I think that the 2nd image that you've attached above, from "666"  - which has the Pope wearing a blue/purple suit - is closer to my memory. Thank you. I'll accept this answer but I want to make a note of the Battle Pope comment in case this comment helps someone else.