# Comic with a chainsmoking priest fighting demons (no, it's not Constantine)

Tags: story-identification, comics

It's been nagging at me for ages: around 2000, I read a comic book about a badass priest fighting a world-spanning demonic invasion. I'm 99.5% sure it was *not* Constantine, even though the characters do have some overlap. What I remember:

- Extremely tough and burly (a bit like TV's Reacher, perhaps)
- Does wear a typical Catholic priest's outfit (black suit and shirt, white collar)
- Highly adept at all sorts of weapons and fighting styles
- *Not* supernaturally gifted IIRC
- Basically never seen without a cigar in his mouth
- Very sarcastic and disillusioned
- Short, blonde hair

Anyone might have an idea what book that was?

Comment: Is it Constantine? It sounds like Constantine...

Comment: I know it sounds similar, but AFAIK Constantine is dark-haired and more on the lanky side, so IIRC it must be a different character.

Comment: Constantine is frequently portrayed as blond https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/hellblazer/images/0/0d/013013_constantine2.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20150509140345

Comment: Oh, okay - but the other traits still don't really match (or else it was a _very_ free interpretation of the character).

Comment: Was it an old priest or a young priest?

Comment: See below, more on the young side (30-ish maybe?)

Answer (score 8):

Hah, just as I was reading the comments, Stackexchange actually linked a new related question in the sidebar that hadn't been there before: [German Comic - Pope Fighting Evil - Papst bekämpft das Böse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241861/german-comic-pope-fighting-evil-papst-bek%C3%A4mpft-das-b%C3%B6se?rq=1)

And the [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/241891) is exactly what I had in mind! To summarize: it's really not Constantine, it's also not German, but it's a French comic series called "666" from the '90s with badass Pope Carmody (not just any priest, mind you) slaughtering demons.